# How to use toast notification in ContextProvider?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to use the toast-notification. So I have it like:

```
import { useToast } from "react-native-toast-notifications";
export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [token, setToken] = useState(AsyncStorageLib.getItem("Token"));
    const [user, setUser] = useState(!!token);
    const show = useToast();

    const onLogin = (email, password) => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        loginRequest(email, password)
            .then((u) => {
                setUser(u);

                setToken(u.token);
                setIsLoading(false);
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                setIsLoading(false);
                show("Login failed!", { type: "error" });
            });
    };
```

and my App.js looks like:

```
return (
        <>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <ToastProvider>
                    <AuthContextProvider>
                        <Navigation />
                    </AuthContextProvider>
                </ToastProvider>
            </ThemeProvider>
            <ExpoStatusBar style="auto" />
        </>
    );
```

But then I get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: showToast is not a function
```

Question: how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

You AuthContextProvider shoud be child of ToastProvider.

`const toast = useToast()`

```
toast.show({
message: "Login failed!",
type: "error",
})
```

Comment: you are trying to get showToast and as doumentation there is no **showToast** but **show**

Comment: I can see you return nothing in Authcotextprovider olease first complete Authcontextprovider thing and I also update the then use the code it will be more helpful

Comment: Is this error related to react native toast try to remove toast line and its import and then check that the same is still exist beacuse this error is not from react native toast but cause by something else